# Cannot push newly created item in MongoDB to AngularJS array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, mongodb

I stuck for 2 full days on this issues.
I use Ruby On Rails, MongoDB and AngularJS. When I add a new record to the database, this record is successfully added in the collection (table), but I cannot get this record automatically displayed into the current list of items.

I am doing it this way:

```
$scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, response.id));

$scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, {id: response.id})); //tried also
$scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, {_id: response.id.$oid})); //tried also
$scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, {id: response.id.$oid})); //tried also
$scope.posts.push(response.id); //tried also
$scope.posts.push(response); //tried also
```

The record still not get among the existing ones. After refreshing the page is this record already displayed among others. (just FYI - deleting record and `splice` works well).

After some investigating, it might be caused by the structure of MongoDB collection/documents?

I've noticed that when I load data from MongoDB database, the hash looks like this:

```
Resource {_id: Object, body: null, created_at: "2015-10-26T19:14:13.016Z", starred: null, title: "u8u88u8u", updated_at: "2015-10-26T19:14:13.016Z", __proto__: ...}
```

Notice the first item (underscore) - `_id`.

```
Resource {id: Object, title: "bla bla bla", body: null, starred: null, created_at: "2015-10-27T15:40:04.462Z"…}
```

Notice the first item - `id`.

May be the problem that I am trying to push to the array an item that contains `id` instead of `id`, so the structure of the hash is not identical?

I cannot make this work for two days, so this might be a non-sense what I am typing here, but trying to put down on the paper all possible issues of why the newly created record is not automatically push to the existing array of items.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you choose to use Mongo?

Comment: If you collect data from Mongo databse, you should point to an element by using _id instead of id. It is prefixed property by mongo.

Comment: @Miha2255 thanks for the comment. But you mean in the `response` variable? Or where exactly?